# How to disable middle button showing a page thumbnail in Adobe Reader?

Tags: adobe-reader

Middle click and drag in Adobe Reader scrolls the page, as it does in most Windows applications. However, middle click and release (without dragging) shows a page thumbnail.

[image: thumbnail]

Is there any way to turn off the thumbnail-showing behavior? It's annoying when I just try to scroll the page and suddenly a box pops up, obstructing the text.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot? I ask because I can not duplicate the same issue with my Adobe Reader.

Comment: Which version u use?

Comment: This is what the thumbnail looks like: http://i.imgur.com/K6AQY.png I'm using Reader 10.1.13, but it has been happening in previous versions as well.

Comment: Do you still want to scroll with middle-click? If not, then your mouse drivers should have capability to outright disable middle-click for acrobat reader.

Comment: Well, if I didn't want to scroll with middle click, I just wouldn't use it...

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there is not a direct way to do this so you have to use some trick like [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/). There is another [question](https://superuser.com/questions/246607/how-to-invert-scroll-wheel-in-certain-applications-using-autohotkey) I found where user is using mouse wheel as hand in Adobe reader.

The best way to set the keys according to your wish and do whatever you want to. But I think this will cause to not scroll down through the mouse wheel after this.